# Protractor ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I am trying to select all the todo's on https://www.angularjs.org/. However its only changing the first one. How do I select all the elements:

```
element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos')).then(function(rows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {                
        element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos')).get(i).element(by.model('todo.done')).click();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`.each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
var todos = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
todos.each(function(todo) {
    todo.element(by.model('todo.done')).click();

    browser.sleep(1000);  // hardcoded delay 
});
```

Comment: Tried it ... its still not checking the second checkbox

Comment: adding sleep(1000) helped to check both the boxes.

Comment: @mac_new okay, updated the answer appropriately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var todos = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
todos.get(1).click();
todos.get(2).click();
```

element.all will collect all elements of givent locator and get() will select the element specific element.
It works like array.